# 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend'

Tags: xcode, app-store

I try to upload this app to App Store but it shows this bug all the time. I don't find it in any info key plist 
What should I do?
[image: alert]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It s the "Application does not run in background" key.

Comment: I need to delete it? it doesn't work after to upload the project to App Store